# C++ priority_queue using map with lambda comparator error

Tags: c++, dictionary, lambda, comparator, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement my own key comparator for std::proirity_queue as follows:

```
funtion insertInPQ(vector<int> nums){
   map<int,int> m;
   for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
     m[nums[i]]++;

   auto comp = []( int a, int b ) 
   { 
        return m[a] < m[b]; 
   };
   priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)> pq(comp);
   for(auto it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++)
        pq.push(it->first);
}
```

But its giving error:

**In lambda function:
Line 10: Char 23: error: passing 'const std::map' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
             return m[a] < m[b];**

Comment: `funtion` is 1. misspelled and 2. not how you declare a function in C++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your capture list of your lambda (the square brackets) is empty, I guess there should be

```cpp
[&m]
```

there ?

Next, if you search for the operator[] of std::map, you will find that this can only operate on non-const maps (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). Your lambda is likely being invoked with a const map instead. So try using

```cpp
return m.at(a) < m.at(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're lamdba is wrong, you either need to compare the two arguments or capture the `m` variable.

```
auto comp = []( int a, int b ) 
{ 
     return a < b; 
};
```

Or:

```
auto comp = [m]( int a, int b ) 
{ 
     return m[a] < m[b]; 
};
```

It depends what you want exactly to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think `m` is not known within the context of your lambda. You have to pass it as a [capture](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
   auto comp = [m]( int a, int b ) 
   { 
        return m[a] < m[b]; 
   };
```